# Have I need to record data manually to record the changes with time within core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I tend to show the everyday changes on the chart view in iOS app which using Core Data.

As the result, I need to know the data's fluctuation in the pass.

I know the managedObjectContext will record some data, but not persistence.

My question is that

**Can I fetch data's changes from Core Data directly?**

**or It is necessary to record manually when every time change.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each change and save the context. Usually you would have an entity with some value attribute(s) and a date attribute and you would insert a new instance each time something changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply : )  You means if I have 'Card' Entity and every time this card change attribute(s) , then I mark the date of change, right? But this way I only know the latest modify date; however, I want to know the changes of this card in day or in week or month. Should I create a entity to record all this kind of data?

Comment: you could have a new entity which is CardHistory, yes

Comment: So, I can have card entity which has a to-many relationship to cardHistory, and when I need it , fetch the card Entity to get all cards with it own history. Thanks a lot, I figure it out, haha. Thanks for answering.